# What exactly is the "Host" field in the Postgresql setup?

Tags: postgresql

In the setup of a postgresql, it says:

Please verify the installation details:

```
Host: 
UserName:
Password:
Port:
```

I'm trying to figure out in what cases do we leave localhost, and what else can we use? Does the input take IPs?

In what case would you use a different IP in that field?

Comment: 1) If this is about Postgres why the MySQL tag? 2) The docs [Connection keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) have the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Host is the address of the System on which database is created and stored.
If you are running the software/application on same system on database, then hostname is localhost, if you are accessing it from another System, then host is the ip address of the system.

Comment: Not really. Read the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-MULTIPLE-HOSTS). Correct your answer or delete it.